# How do you use the numjac function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, ode, differential-equations

The [documentation online](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/47204/versions/1/previews/A3_Distill/numjac.m/index.html?access_key=) for this particular function is poor, and I was looking for an example on how to use it. It seems to take in 9+ arguments, but I'm not entirely sure what they even are. I am working on implementing function using the trapezoidal rule, however, I am missing the functions that compute the partial derivatives with respect to y and t. I believe that calculating one for t in MATLAB is another case, but here, I'm just trying to use MATLAB to compute it for y.

I'm using the following input initially:

```
func = @(t,y)(y.^2+y+t);
interval = [0 1];
y0 = 0;

[steps, derivY, derivJ, W, inverseW] = getTrapezoidalODEValues(func, interval, y0)
```

I set up the function like this:

```
function [h,J,T,W,iW] = getTrapezoidalODEValues(odefun,tspan,y0,options)
    if (nargin==3)
        options = odeset();
    end

    h = NaN; J(0) = NaN; T(0) = NaN; W(0) = NaN; iW = NaN;

    [t,yy] = ode(odefun,tspan,y0,options);
    [nstep,ndim] = size(yy);

    d = 1/(2+sqrt(2));

    for j=2:nsteps
        h = t(j)-t(j-1);
        I = eye(???,???); % identity matrix
        quadpoly = ???; % the quadratic polynomial
        J(j-1) = numjac(???); % <--partial derivative of odefun with respect to y
        T(j-1) = ???; % partial derivative of odefun with respect to t
        W(j-1) = I - h .* d .* J;
        iW(j-1) = inv(W(j-1));
    end
end
```

Comment: The documentation for `numjac` seems fine to me. Which part do you find ambiguous? This is more of a math question. You can compute partials numerically with any typical finite difference methods. You can take advantage of `gradient` and `diff` [functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numerical-integration-and-differentiation.html) for speed.

Comment: Other than that, can you clarify your question? What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? The code needs to be commented with purposes, not just memos like ??? and identify matrix. Typeset some formulas and link images where necessary. It is *highly* uninviting to have to interpret your intentions and methods from reading your code line by line.

Comment: I was just hoping for an example of how to use it and what types of parameters you can use. Also, if you may have any documentation I haven't come across yet, maybe a link to that. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @oliviahamon: I linked it in the first sentence of your question with an edit. The online version is only a little tidier than what you can from `help numjac` in the console. (When you say 'online documentation', it's better provide a link.) The linked page describes the syntax in details. Although, do you already know what the function can do? If you don't understand its documentation, what are you using it for?